# Problems with layouts and understanding warnings

Tags: java, android

My questions are about android programing with eclipse.
First problem is LinearLayout.
I've created new LinearLayouts but their names are the same. In my opinion they are LinearLayout1 and LinearLayout2 but, this does not happen.
This photo:

[image]

Second problem is:

[image]

I'm just learning java, so I don't understand warnings.

Comment: Switch to XML and hover cursor over warning to see the message. The "Problems" view also helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your second problem are just warnings, not fatal problems (those would be "errors", in red). But anyway:

- The first means you should remove the debug marker from the manifest (debuggable=true).
- The second means you should be targeting the last version of the Android API (19). Change your targetSdkVersion in manifest to reflect this.
- The third, about inputType is just a hint you provide to edit text for it to display the appropriate semantic context for the user. For example, an email type would also make the keyboard display an at sign (@) prominently on the screen. A URL input type could make it show the dedicated .com key.
- The last warning is self I explanatory: change match_parent to 0dip because you are already using layout weights.

The first issue is just naming. Show us the full XML code and we can better answer you. I shall edit this answer to reflect the changes. However, know in advance that this is nothing. Just go to the source edit panel and define your own id fields for the LinearLayouts. If you did that, you're fine. But since we can't judge your "opinion", we can only know when you post your source code for the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: 
You can change the way each of the Android layouts/views are displayed in the Eclipse Outline View by giving each of those items an id.

Second problem:
The warnings that you've shown are *just* warnings and are fairly self-explanatory (avoid hardcoding debug mode, target latest versions of Android, specify an inputType or hint, etc.). I'm sure you could Google each one (or search on StackOverflow) if you want more information to properly resolve them.

Alternatively, you could turn off warning/errors inside Eclipse `Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`.